# Symfony framework : updating live servers

Tags: php, symfony

I have product implemented using Symfony 2+ framework which is live.

We are updating new features or fixing bugs regularly.

Our problem is that when we update server, we need to clear cache. All users who logged in that time will loose sessions and also sometimes data (For example when they are filling some form and submit session will expire).

Is there any way to avoid this? Or what are the best practice we can follow while updating Symfony projects?

Answer (score 1):

You should store your session-files outside of the app's `cache` directory.

Read about SaveHandlers on Symfony's docs site: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html

Try to store session files in `/tmp` or smth like that. You can do it in php.ini or with next code:

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
ini_set('session.save_path', /tmp');
```

Then you can just use next construction:

```
$session = new Session(new NativeSessionStorage());
```

You can also just change `session.save_path` parameter in your config. But I had some problems with it (can't remember what it were about).

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Capifony](http://capifony.org/) deploy tool for Symfony you can keep Symfony2 sessions after deploy doing this settings:

config.yml

```
framework:
    session:
        save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sessions/"
```

You have to add also your sessions directory to Capifony’s :shared_children

deploy.rb

```
set :shared_children, [log_path, ..., app_path + "/sessions"]
```

described [here](http://capifony.org/cookbook/how-to-keep-sessions-after-deploy.html)